# Division program in C

Tags: c, linux, division

I'm doing a program that shows how to make division in binary code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int division(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) // fonction division
{
    int i;
    b = (b << 16);
    for(i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        a = (a << 1);
        if(a >= b)
        {
            a = a - b;
            a = a + 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i, a, b, d, N;
    unsigned short c;

    FILE* rep;
    rep = fopen("reponse.txt", "w"); /* ouverture du fichier */

    printf("Entrer le nombre de division a effectuer");
    scanf("%i", &N);

    printf("Veuillez inserer la ou les divisions a effectuer\n");
    printf("de la facon suivante : a/b\n");

    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i/%i", &a, &b); /* il suffira d'entrer a/b */
            d = division(a, b); /* la division de a par b */
            c = unsigned short(d); /* les 16 premiers bits */
            d = (d >> 16); /* les 16 premiers bits */
            fprintf(rep, "division %i : %i/%i = %d reste %i\n", i, a, b, c, d);
    }
    fclose(rep); /* fermeture du fichier */
    return 0;
}
```

It shows to me `error: expected expression before 'unsigned'` in this line `c = unsigned short(d);`
I don't know exactly what's the problem!
Can someone help me please? I'm under Linux Ubuntu 12.10 coding on Code::Blocks

Comment: what are intening to do in this line c = unsigned short(d);?

Comment: Simply casting an integer into a short value doesn't gives you the first 16 bits.
Try using structs to keep the remainder. I'm not French, so don't know what you try to achieve.

Comment: C'est pas cool les commentaires en français pour la communauté... division ==> divide

Comment: @Aubin The code is international lol. I will change comments later :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = unsigned short(d);
```

This is not C.

To convert from one type to another you can use the cast operator:

```
c = (unsigned short) d;
```

Note that as there is an implicit conversion between `unsigned int` and `unsigned short`, the cast is not needed and this is equivalent:

```
c = d;
```

Comment: Thank you :) other problem /bin/sh: l: g++: not found when compiling

Comment: With -Wall -pedantic, c = d; produce a warning, the cast is necessary, at least for readability.

Comment: @Aubin `gcc` is free to print extra diagnostics, but C does not require the implementation to print a diagnostic for `c = d;` here.

Comment: Thank you @ouah. I have a problem with my code. I will verify it

Comment: Your code is in *C*, you need `gcc` not `g++` to compile it (even if `g++` can compile C and Fortran in addition of C++). And you certainly want `gcc -Wall -g` then use `gdb` to debug it. The `g++` command will link you C++ libraries, and you want only the *C* standard library `libc.so.6`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How? I'm new in Ubuntu. In Windows, it compiles automatically!

Comment: Run `aptitude install gcc` (or `gcc-4.7`) then use the `gcc` compiler *thru the command line*. You don't need Code::Blocks for such simple programs, just a plain editor like `emacs` or `gedit` (or maybe `geany` or `vim`), which you probably already have. You just run the compilation command in a terminal. Don't forget to use `gcc -Wall -g divlafore.c -o divlafore` to compile, and learn how to use `gdb`. You'll need it.

Comment: Doesn't work! Whatever, my code works perfectly. Thank yall :)